# Как получить ID

Tags: php, mysql

Вот сама страница

```
        <?php
     require_once("../connect.php");
    $query = "SELECT *
    FROM comments
    -- WHERE is_visible = 1
    WHERE product <> 'Лендинг'
    ORDER BY created_at DESC";
    $com = $pdo->query($query);
    while($comments = $com->fetch()) {
    // Обрабатываем сообщения перед выводом,
    // чтобы исключить вставку JavaScript-кода
    $comments['nickname'] = htmlspecialchars($comments['nickname']);
    $comments['phone'] = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($comments['phone']));
    $comments['content'] = nl2br(htmlspecialchars($comments['content']));
    echo "<div class='coll'>".
    "<span class='author'>{$comments['nickname']}</span>". " | " .
    "<span class='product'>{$comments['product']}</span>". " | " .
    "<span class='date'>{$comments['created_at']}</span>". " | " .
    "<span class='mess'>{$comments['content']}</span>". " | " .
    "<span class='phone'>{$comments['phone']}</span>". " | " .
    "<span class='sizer'>{$comments['sizer']}</span>". " | " .
    "<span class='email'>{$comments['email']}</span>". " | " .
    '<span><a href="del_order.php?id='.['id'].'">Удалить</a></span>' .
    "</div>" . "<br>";
    }
     ?>
```

Вот код удаления

```
    <?php
require_once("../connect.php");
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
$query = sprintf("DELETE
FROM comments
WHERE id = '%d'", $id);
$com = $pdo->query($query);
echo "$query";
?>
```

Я как-то неправильно пытаюсь получить id, подскажите как правильно это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не передаёте id  в ссылку, замените:

> `<a href="del_order.php?id='.['id'].'">Удалить</a>`

на:

```
<a href="del_order.php?id='.$comments['id'].'">Удалить</a>
```

Comment: Понял, новенький просто на этом форуме.
Спасибо и за этот совет)